# Gradle:Could not get unknown property 'appName' for project

Tags: gradle

I have following fragment of build.gradle.

The first line is working fine, if I don't specify version its uses 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
However second line is not working. I am getting "Could not get unknown property 'appName' for project"
Any idea how I can define custom properties in gradle and pass them thru command line?

```
version = "${version != 'unspecified' ? version : '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'}"

appName = "${appName != 'unspecified' ? appName : 'test'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the Porject API's properties in [Gradle DSL doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:version), which is the root cause of your "unknown property" issue.

As you can see the `version` is part of properties of `Project` API, while `appName` is not. You can also use `name` (which refers to the `rootProject.name` in the `setting.gradle`).

Here is my `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'test-project'
```

Here is snippet that I put into `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    version = "${version != 'unspecified' ? version : '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'}"
    println ("version is $version")

    appName = "${name != 'unspecified' ? name : 'test'}"
    println ("name is $appName")

    projectName = "${project != 'unspecified' ? project : 'test'}"
    println ("projectName is $projectName")
}
```

Here is the output:

```
> Configure project :
version is 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
name is test-project
projectName is root project 'test-project'
```